# ajax post request contentType

Tags: jquery, ajax, multipartform-data, spring-rest

I created a  html form with multipart, I should form a request with form fields and a file which is uploaded. I used ajax POST request but I don't know exactly which contentType to use. tried with 'multipart/form-data' but I get BadRequest from server.

```
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('name',"somename");
        fd.append('regionalName',"newString");
        fd.append('constituencyNumber',122);
        fd.append('districtId',21);
        fd.append('file',document.getElementById('filePicker').files[0]);

        ajax({
           url: "http://192.168.1.157:8080/constituency",
           type: "POST",
           data:fd,
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,
           cache: false,
           success: function () {
               console.log("success");
           },
           error: function () {
               console.log("filaed");
           }
        });
```

In server side

```
@RequestMapping(value="/constituency", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public BaseResponseDto addConstituency(@RequestBody FormDataMultiPart constituencyDto){
        log.info("addConstituency");
        return constituencyService.addConstituency(constituencyDto);
    }
```

Request not reach my controller. Anything I missed out!!

Comment: try with comment out `filePicker` `append`

Comment: @ParthTrivedi  Tried that, BadRequest

Comment: In ajax call try with this value for url "/constituency"

Comment: May be problem with route.

Comment: @ketha kavya, then how it knows the domain of the request

Comment: @SharanDeSilva Have you tried with that?

Comment: tried, but nothing changed

Comment: Do you have any of these set? php options: post_max_size, upload_max_filesize, max_input_time

Comment: @KethaKavya thanks, but I am not using php, but I think that my post request size is exceeded. but I don't know how to configure this with spring? Do you?

Comment: Can you try with contentType:undefined. This also might be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688838/400-bad-request-when-uploading-byte-with-spring-resttemplate-to-springmvc-rest